# How to keep content in a container, but extend it's background full width in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to develop a design that looks like:

[image: Design image]

In the design above the red lines are the sides of the container. I am keeping the content of the section within a container div like so:

```
.container {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But I would then want the blue background div to the content on the left to extend the full width of the screen, breaking out of the container while keeping the content within the blue background inside the container.

I can't seem to find the best way to dev this out keeping the content in the container, but the blue background div to extend all the way to the left of the screen.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Comment: you can pseudo styles to to that. add bg to left container, remove container overflow hidden, add pseduo style :before of left container and add width 100% and right 100%

Comment: @Manjunath Just tried that approach and it works to get the blue background to go full width and keep the content within the container. But the only issue is with the blue background being position:absolute it doesn't grow in height to fit the size of the content

Comment: @misorude That link doesn't really explain what I am trying to do. Yes they are taking a div full width outside of the container, but what I am trying to do is keep it 50% of the width and also have content within that element that is breaking the container, like in my example image above

Comment: So what, the same principle should be applicable “on one side” only as well … did you even _try_ anything based on this?

Comment: @misorude Yes I did try it... there is still the issue that I can't keep the content inside the wrap and the blue background to extend outside that wrap. I stated that in my response, because the 50% width wasn't the main issue.

Comment: So what is stopping you from countering the effect of that negative margin(-left) by an equal amount of padding-left, to push the content to the inside again …?

Comment: you can just add right left bottom and top to 0 leaving width and height

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you are looking for is to use a pseudo element to simulate a background.
The key is to position the pseudo element, and to give him the proper size.

Here is an exemple:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:after {
  content:'';
  display: table;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.w50 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.w50:first-child:before {
    content:'';
    background: #ddd;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50vw;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="w50">
    <h2>First child</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore eum laboriosam nulla amet. Commodi obcaecati ipsum eum, ea numquam reprehenderit quidem maiores corrupti minus accusantium ipsam error labore sint dolorem.
    </p>
        <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore eum laboriosam nulla amet. Commodi obcaecati ipsum eum, ea numquam reprehenderit quidem maiores corrupti minus accusantium ipsam error labore sint dolorem.
    </p>
        <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore eum laboriosam nulla amet. Commodi obcaecati ipsum eum, ea numquam reprehenderit quidem maiores corrupti minus accusantium ipsam error labore sint dolorem.
    </p>
        <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore eum laboriosam nulla amet. Commodi obcaecati ipsum eum, ea numquam reprehenderit quidem maiores corrupti minus accusantium ipsam error labore sint dolorem.
    </p>
    
  </div>
  <div class="w50">
    <h2>Second child</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet tempora illum eligendi, praesentium saepe error itaque reiciendis. Placeat sint quasi ea obcaecati soluta accusamus. Reiciendis incidunt praesentium quidem commodi expedita?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is how to achieve it :

- Add `position: relative;` to the element which needs the background.
- Add a peusdo element `:before`.
- Add `position: absolute;, width: 50vh; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` to that pseudo element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for your problem. Adjust the fixed sizes to what you want to achieve. Try to view my example in full screen.

```css
body{
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div.containerA {
  position: relative; 
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

div.containerB {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

div.contentA {
  width: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

div.contentB {
  position: relative;
  right: -100px;
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="containerA">
  <div class="containerB">
      <div class="contentA">
      <h1>Title 1</h1>
     <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </p>
      </div>

       <div class="contentB">
       <h1>Title 2</h1>
      <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </p>
      </div>
  <div>    
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two columns aligned to the centre of the screen with a max width of half the container size

```
.article-container{
max-width:1200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
section{
margin-bottom:2rem;}

.article-grid{
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: stretch;
}
article{
flex:1 50%;
display: flex;
font-family: arial;
 }
article:nth-of-type(1){
background-color:blue;
color:white;
justify-content: flex-end;
}
article:nth-of-type(2){
background-color:red;
color:white;
justify-content: flex-start;
}

.article-inner-grid{
max-width: 600px;
}
.article-padding{
padding:2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the section and add the div tag with the class container inside that section and then add background CSS to the section element and other css that you needed to the conatiner